# Subdivide rows into intervals of 50 and take mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to subdivide my dataframe into intervals of 50, then perform the mean of these individual intervals, and then create a new dataframe.

```
            2           3           4
    0       20.229517   21.444166   19.528986
    1       19.420929   21.029457   18.895041
    2       19.214857   21.122784   19.228065
    3       19.454653   21.148373   19.249720
    4       20.152334   22.183264   20.149488
    ...     ...         ...         ...
    9995    20.673738   22.252024   21.587578
    9996    21.948563   24.904633   23.962317
    9997    24.318361   27.220770   25.322933
    9998    24.570177   26.371695   23.503048
    9999    23.274368   25.145500   22.028172
    10000 rows × 3 columns
```

That is a 200 x 3, with the mean values. I would  like to do this in pandas if possible. Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use integer division by `50` and pass to `groupby` with aggregate `mean`:

```
np.random.seed(2020)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(10000, 3)))
print (df)
             0         1         2
0     0.986277  0.873392  0.509746
1     0.271836  0.336919  0.216954
2     0.276477  0.343316  0.862159
3     0.156700  0.140887  0.757080
4     0.736325  0.355663  0.341093
       ...       ...       ...
9995  0.524481  0.454835  0.108934
9996  0.816516  0.354442  0.224834
9997  0.090518  0.887463  0.444833
9998  0.413673  0.315459  0.691306
9999  0.656559  0.113400  0.063397

[10000 rows x 3 columns]
```

---

```
df = df.groupby(df.index // 50).mean()
print (df)
            0         1         2
0    0.537299  0.484187  0.512674
1    0.446181  0.503547  0.455493
2    0.504955  0.446041  0.464571
3    0.567661  0.494185  0.519785
4    0.485611  0.553636  0.396364
..        ...       ...       ...
195  0.516285  0.433178  0.526545
196  0.476906  0.474619  0.465957
197  0.497325  0.511659  0.490382
198  0.564468  0.453961  0.467758
199  0.520884  0.455529  0.479706

[200 rows x 3 columns]
```